# Page not found due to htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've tried pretty much everything i can think of, I've basically moved from Mac OS to Windows OS webserver with my project (testing essentially). When i access any other page from my server I get the "Page Not Found" error, however it works if i add `index.php/location`, anyway here is some of my settings:

Initially i have checked if mod_rewrite is enabled by adding this: `in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())` to a conditional statement which responded as true so i know mod_rewrite is in face enabled.

Here is my .htaccess file which is located in the main directory of my project (with index.php):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    Options -Indexes 
    DirectoryIndex index.php 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Have also tried as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` and written it outside the `<ifModule>` tags.

Here are some of my codeigniter settings:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I have also tried including the `index.php` in the index_page and tried `REQUEST_URI` for the uri_protocol and nothing seems to be working.

Sidenote: It runs perfectly on my mac and linux (Raspberry Pi).

Can you suggest any alternative methods or spot something I've missed.

EDIT:
httpd.conf i have done the following

```
<directory />
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
</directory>
```

ALL instances of `AllowOverride None` have been changed to `AllowOverride All`

The following has been uncommented/enabled:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: I have to ask (as there was another question on here with the same problem). Are you certain you are using Apache on the Windows server?

Comment: I am using MAMP Beta for windows, and i should hope Apache is working as i can load the home page :)

Comment: Just checking -- another question here someone was wondering why their htaccess did not work but they were using IIS.  Speaking of htaccess not working, are you certain it is being processed?  By default, some setups do not process .htaccess files.  I often find it useful to make a purposeful mistake and make sure you get a 500 error.

Comment: Also try removing the ifmodule statements. Perhaps mod_rewrite is not installed - I know you tried to test it via PHP but best to leave PHP out of this until you know you have both mod_rewrite and .htaccess being processed correctly.

Comment: I've tried that and nothing happens

Comment: try `<IfModule rewrite_module>`. `mod_rewrite.c` seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch your default .htaccess file in php.

1. Make a new file in your codeigniter root directory named ".htaccess"
2. Paste below code into this new file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /leo/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Save it and it should work now.

Comment: My main .htaccess file is the on from my codeigniter directory so that didn't make a difference :/ sorry for being unclear and thanks for the response

Comment: @Matthew Can you try to remove all the contents and just paste this four lines in your .htaccess main file and also put the path to your codeigniter root directory in your 'base_url' config setting. i.e. $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/leo/';

Comment: I have done as you have asked and still get the same issue, however of course adding index.php to the URL breaks it :/